# as.Date returns different formats if sapply or not

Tags: r, date, datetime, format, as.date

I have a data frame with a date columns that I need to convert into a format R recognizes as a date.

```
> dataframe
        Date        Sum
1   06/09/15       2.51
2   06/09/15       3.75
3   06/09/15       3.50
...
```

I first converted it using `sapply`:

`> dataframe$Date2<-sapply(dataframe$Date,as.Date,format="%m/%d/%y")`

This returned the date as the number of days from Jan 1, 1970:

```
> dataframe
        Date        Sum      Date2
1   06/09/15       2.51      16595
2   06/09/15       3.75      16595
3   06/09/15       3.50      16595
...
```

Later on I tried converting it without `sapply`:

`> dataframe$Date3<-as.Date(dataframe$Date,format="%m/%m/%d")`

This, in turn, returned

```
> dataframe
        Date        Sum      Date2       Date3
1   06/09/15       2.51      16595  2015-09-15
2   06/09/15       3.75      16595  2015-09-15
3   06/09/15       3.50      16595  2015-09-15
...
```

These are two very different, apparently incompatible formats. Why does `sapply` return one format (days since the origin), while doing without it returns another (%Y-%m-%d)?

Now, obviously I could just ignore one method and go forth never using `sapply` with `as.Date` but I'd like to know why it reads differently. I am also struggling to convert the Date3 vector into the Date2 format.

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Why does `sapply` provide a different date format?
2. How do I convert a date-recognizable sequence (such as mm/dd/yyyy) into the number of days since 1 Jan 1970?

Comment: `sapply` coerces it to numeric form.  It is better to use the vectorized option you used.  If you need to convert back specify the `origin`. i.e. `as.Date(sapply(dat1$Date, as.Date,format='%m/%d/%y'), origin='1970-01-01')`

Comment: Why do you need `sapply` in this case?

Comment: @Pascal I shouldn't have. Before the attempts described above I tried as.Date without sapply, but using dataframe[1] instead of dataframe$Date and received an error. My response was to try a new method, aka sapply, before I realized that dataframe$Date would solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to the second part of your original question.  To obtain the number of days since the epoch (1 Jan 1970) for a date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` you can use the `as.Date()` function:

```
some.date <- as.Date("06/17/2015", "%m/%d/%Y")
days.since.epoch <- unclass(some.date)

> days.since.epoch
[1] 16616
```

Internally, R stores the date object `some.date` in terms of the number of days since the epoch (1 Jan 1970), and calling `unclass()` reveals this internal representation.

Answer (score 1):

when working with dates I love to use `lubridate` as it is in my eyes much easier to use and much more intuitive then the base functions.
Your second question could be done with the following code:

```
require(lubridate)
dataframe$Date2<-difftime(dataframe$Date3,dmy("01-01-1970"),units="days")
```

depending on if you want to have the 1. January 1970 as day 1 or not you may have to add a +1 to the end of this line.

I don't really work with sapply and tapply directly (I prefer to use plyr for this) so I can't help with your first question.

Answer (score 1):

### 1.

If you don't use the argument `simplify=FALSE`, `sapply` will use the command `unlist` to transform the answer from a list into a vector. `unlist` coerces the list elements to be of common type. From the [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unlist.html):

> Where possible the list elements are coerced to a common mode during the unlisting, and so the result often ends up as a character vector. Vectors will be coerced to the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression: pairlists are treated as lists.

Because `Date` is not a part of hierarchy, `unlist` can not coerce to `Date`. I am not sure exactly why `unlist` chooses to coerce to integer (and not character), but it has probably something to do with the fact that `Date` objects are stored as integers.

### 2.

To convert a `Date` to the number of days since 1 Jan 1970, you can use `as.numeric`

```
today=Sys.Date()
> today
[1] "2019-04-16"
> as.numeric(today)
[1] 18002
```

and to go back

```
> as.Date(18002, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2019-04-16"
```